# How to add N dynamic form fields in Django without using javascript / ajax?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class AddCoffee(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coffee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coffee_price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Now, from this model, I get all the `coffee_name`s:

```
coffee_names = AddCoffee.objects.values_list('coffee_name', flat=True)
```

Now, what I want to do (and I couldn't find any way of doing it even if there're some topics closely related here on SO) is to:

- generate `len(coffee_names)` `ChoiceField`s with the labels being each coffee name and the values being a list from 0 to 50. Something like this:

  ```
  class RequestCoffeeForm(forms.Form):
      coffee_names = AddCoffee.objects.values_list('coffee_name', flat=True)

      for name in coffee_names:
          forms.ChoiceField(label="{}".format(name),
                            choices=[x for x in range(51)])

      """
      Suppose coffee_names = ["ABC", "DEF"]

      I should have two `ChoiceFields` as follows:

      ABC = forms.ChoiceField(label="ABC", choices=[x for x in range(51)])
      DEF = forms.ChoiceField(label="DEF", choices=[x for x in range(51)])
      """
  ```

How can I achieve this ? Things are a bit ambiguous in my head on how'd I store later this dynamic fields in a model / view.

---

I've tried:

```
class RequestCoffeeForm(forms.Form):
    coffee_names = AddCoffee.objects.values_list('coffee_name', flat=True)

    for name in coffee_names:
        name = forms.ChoiceField(label="{}".format(name), choices=((str(x), x) for x in range(51)))
```

Which is then called in my view:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def request_coffee_page(request):
    form = RequestCoffeeForm(request.POST or None)

    return render(request, "request_coffee.html", {'form': form})
```

And then in my template:

```
{{ form.name.label_tag }}
{{ form.name }}
```

The above only prints the last coffee_name. How can I print them all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have time to try it out, but AFAICT this *might* work:

```
class RequestCoffeeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequestCoffeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        choices = [(str(x), x) for x in range(51)]
        # store it as attribute in case we need it later...
        self.coffee_names = AddCoffee.objects.values_list('coffee_name', flat=True)

        for name in self.coffee_names:
            self.fields[coffee_name] = forms.ChoiceField(
                label=coffee_name, choices=choices
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class RequestCoffeeForm(forms.Form):
    COFFEE_CHOICES = []
    coffee_names = AddCoffee.objects.values_list('coffee_name', flat=True)

    for name in coffee_names:
        COFFEE_CHOICES.append((str(name).lower(), str(name)))
    forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_LIST)
```

`choices` has to be an [iterable of 2-tuples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices). For an example see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you list the label and the values in the templates ?

Comment: And what's `COFFEE_CHOICES.append((str(name).lower(), str(name)))` for ? You didn't use it anywhere. How will I know the name of each field ?

Comment: @MrGrj ChoiceField will be a select widget (dropdown list) with coffee names taken from COFFEE_CHOICE which is a list of 2-tuples: the second tuple's member is the coffee nume in human-readable form.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer ? I'm interested in how I'll be able to print each of these on my template :)

Comment: @MrGrj I think I didn't understand what you really want. I thought you want a [dropdown list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) with coffee names from which to select one (or more).

Comment: No :) I wanted for each coffee name a dropdown with values from 0 to 50

Comment: @MrGrj i'm in a hurry now but i'l try to solve it later. I'll update the answer